# Is there a way to launch ScreenSharing from the Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, screen-sharing

How can I launch OS X's ScreenSharing from the command line and have it connect to a specified system?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
open vnc://server.address[:port]
```

Comment: open vnc://user@pass:server:port also works if you want to pass in some credentials.  The security risks of doing this is yours to consider.

Comment: `open vnc://user@server:port` is also useful and doesn't have the security risks associated with having your password show up in the process list

Comment: I never thought to type `man open` before today. It can do a lot.

Comment: Correct syntax to use password is `vnc://user:password@server:port`

Comment: Know of a way to use the VNC password as an argument to this?  Thanks

Comment: @PeterBecich You are funny. You put your question exactly under that comment that **answers** your questions.

Comment: What also works is `vnc://:password@server:port` --- meaning when you dont have a user name, but a password (our vnc servers are configured like that).

Comment: I want to do this and monitor for when screen sharing closes. That's not possible with `open`.

Comment: If you’ve already connected via Screen Sharing and allowed it to save your password (by ticking “Remember this password in my keychain”), you can use `open vnc://@server` to connect with the stored password, so you don’t have to press the Connect button.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access for assistive devices activated in System Preferences, you can try saving the following AppleScript in AppleScript Editor and executing it via command line:

```
tell application "Screen Sharing"
    activate # start Screen Sharing if not running yet
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "a" using command down # this will cause the address to clear
        keystroke "127.0.0.1" # replace with your host
        key code 36 # press enter
    end tell
end tell
```

Save as `Sharing.scpt`, and execute as `osascript /path/to/Sharing.scpt`.